# convert to valid json format in react js

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, object

I have below object.

`{
    Inputs : {
      key : value,
      key: valu
 }},`

I want to convert it into json format JSON.stringify(Inputs) which is giving a format like below which is wrong and hence my code is failing.

`"{"Inputs":{"key":"value","key":"value"}}"`

I dont want double quote in the initial position. It shold be in below format so that my code will work.

```
{"Inputs":{"key":"value","key":"value"}}
```

Any help please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `JSON.stringify()` returns a string. A string is enclosed in quotes.

Comment: @Andreas can you please help me  how should I convert it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the double quotes at start and end, then you don't want a string but an object. For that, your initial object is OK, but if you need the strings you can try:

`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(yourObject))`